# Suggested books that focus on the alt.net style of development? e.g. solid, DI, de-coupling, testing, etc

Tags: c#, alt.net

What .net/c# focused books are there that teach how to develop applications using SOLID principles, unit testing, IoC, etc?

I've watched a few videos on the SOLID principles, but I'd love to learn more about it and in detail on how to go about designing larger scale applications etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Principles-Patterns-Practices-C/dp/0131857258/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1308502374&sr=8-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131857258)

Robert Martin - it is a person who introduced SOLID principles.

Comment: He has also Clean Code book: http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/

Comment: And also The clean coder book: http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Coder-Conduct-Professional-Programmers/dp/0137081073/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1308502920&sr=8-1

Answer (score 1):

About unit testing here is very good book: [http://www.amazon.com/Art-Unit-Testing-Examples-Net/dp/1933988274](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274)

Answer (score 1):

And I am looking forward to read this book about DI in .Net:

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1935182501/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?ie=UTF8&m=ATVPDKIKX0DER](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501)